# kendoButton is not a function, although Kendo is loaded

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, requirejs

I use RequireJS to load Kendo according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671338/inject-kendo-ui-with-requirejs) and it works. jQuery is loaded first, then Kendo. But I got an error "kendoButton is not a function". Here is my app.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/kendo-ui/jquery.min",
        "jquery-ui": "lib/jquery-ui.min",
        "kendo-ui": "lib/kendo-ui" // this is a directory containing all Kendo files
    },
    shim: {
        "kendo-ui/kendo.button.min": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "kendo-ui/kendo.core.min": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});

require(["jquery", "kendo-ui/kendo.core.min", "kendo-ui/kendo.button.min"],
function ($)
{
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
});
```

Kendo [troubleshooting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-common-issues#widgets-are-unavailable-or-undefined) says that jQuery should be included just once (yes, I have) and all the required Kendo files are included (yes, I included kendo.core.min.js).

I use RequireJS 2.2.0, Kendo 2016.1.226, and jQuery version, which is included in the Kendo package. Can someone point out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the baseURL to "js/kendo".

I'm not sure if this has been stated clearly in the documentation. I thought the URL in [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-requirejs#load-kendo-ui-using-requirejs) example is well, an example, but it turns out to be important.